# Google Glass making vignettes using GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I was wondering if is possible to use GDK to develop a app capable of creating vignettes on Glass, like [this](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3405215?hl=en).

Is it possible?

Comment: If you see the tags there is a specific tag [google-gdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-gdk) for that purpose.

Comment: What "vignette" do you want to create (location? time? other?). You might send the image to your server and add the vignette as a response (like the "cats" improve picture demo).

Comment: I imagine the vignette being independent from the running program. If I am using Google Maps, the vignette should be created with the displayed map. If I am using Facebook, the vignette should show the facebook screen... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I imagine your app would need to do 3 steps:

1. Take a screenshot
2. Take a picture
3. Put them together

Steps 2 and 3 are pretty easy and shouldn't be a problem on Glass.

When it comes to step 1, you can take a screenshot from your app in Android by [creating a bitmap from a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android), which should work on Glass as well. But I don't think you can screenshot other apps or the timeline, so I don't think it is doable in general.